# openCV Depth map from two calibrated cameras forming a stereoscopic system

Tags: opencv, depth, stereoscopy

I would like some help in continuing my code using openCV library in order to find the depth values of objects seen in the cameras.

I have already done the calibration and found the dispaity map, i can't find a clear help of how to calculate the depth values of each pixel seen in the two photos taken by the cameras.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link for your problem including a simple algorithm for depth estimation: 
http://www.epixea.com/research/multi-view-coding-thesisse13.html

Comment: thank you so much, but my problem is that i want to continue the code that i used for the calibration.

I have used the code given by: http://blog.martinperis.com/2011/01/opencv-stereo-camera-calibration.html

and i have reached the final step, but i have no idea what is :
d = pointRightImage.X - pointLeftImage.X;

So i though maybe someone could have an easier way to calculate the depth in openCV...

Comment: I don't think the blogpost that you linked will be useful anymore at this point. BTW, if you're working on Computer Vision, don't get scared by mathematical explanations because you need to learn and gain mathematical insight of what you do.

Comment: Yess i agree, i think that's where my problem is, if i knew mathematically what did he mean by "d = pointRightImage.X - pointLeftImage.X" i could create my own code.
Thank you so much for your advice, ill probably work on that

Answer (score 1):

You can use these formula to calculate point cloud 3D coordinates:

```
Z = fB/D
X = (col-w/2)*Z/f
Y = (h/2-row)*Z/f
```

where X, Y, Z are world coordinates, f - focal length of the camera in pixels after calibration, B is a base line or camera separation and D is disparity; col, row represent the column and row coordinates of a pixel in the image with dimensions h, w.

However, if you managed to calibrate your cameras and get a disparity map you have to already know this. Calibration and disparity map calculation is an order of magnitude more complex task than above mentioned calculations.